# Get payment information

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I need to add a parcels select inside my credit card payment module. From what I understand, the file that sends the information to the credit card company takes the card number as well:

```
$payment_cc_number      = $payment->getCcNumber();
```

In this same file there is a line that takes the number of parcels...

```
$payment_parcels        = $this->getConfigData('parcel_number');
```

...but they are not being captured. In the module, I use a simple markup:

```
        <select id="" name="parcels" class="required-entry">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
```

How do I send the value selected by the customer?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the `cc_parcels` field in `sales_flat_order_payment` and `sales_flat_quote_payment` tables and add the code below in the appropriated location of your module.

Block Info class:

```
<?php
class Company_Module_Block_Info extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Cc {
    protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null) {
        $transport = parent::_prepareSpecificInformation($transport);
        if ($this->getInfo()->getCcParcels()) {
            $transport[$this->__('Parcels')] = $this->getInfo()->getCcParcels();
        }
        return $transport;
    }
}
```

Method class:

```
<?php
class Company_Module_Model_Method extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc {
    public function assignData($data) {
        $this->getInfoInstance()->setCcParcels($data['cc_parcels']);
    }
}
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_payment>
                <cc_parcels><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></cc_parcels>
            </sales_convert_quote_payment>
            <sales_convert_order_payment>
                <cc_parcels><to_quote_payment>*</to_quote_payment></cc_parcels>
            </sales_convert_order_payment>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>
</config>
```

form.phtml:

```
<label for="<?php echo $_code ?>_cc_parcels"><?php echo $this->__('Parcels') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
    <select id="<?php echo $_code ?>_cc_parcels" name="payment[cc_parcels]">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

To get the parcels number, you have to get it like `$order->getPayment()->getCcParcels()` (also from `$quote`).